# Enquiry about the bus route

Tags: questions, phrase-requests

Is this correct?

Asking the driver or the another person:

- Does this bus go (or goes) to *X*?
- Do you go to *X*?

Comment: Not "does this bus goes to" - that's not English.

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking directly to the driver, either of the following would work:

> Does this bus go to x?
>
> Do you go to x?

While I would prefer the former, the latter is also somewhat common since it's assumed that the bus and the driver are going to the same places.  However, if you're asking another random person, you definitely want the former as the person's final destination may not be the same as the bus's.

Comment: Does this bus stop at (or near) x?

Answer (score 3):

Not disputing the earlier answer, but as an alternative you might ask:

> Is this the bus for *x*?

or even:

> Is this the *x* bus?

Comment: can I say `IS this the bus to x?` whats the difference?

Comment: Yes; if anything *to* is more correct than *for*, but I wanted to give an example of an alternative that is used and understood.  (Note that you can't freely swap *to* and *for* everywhere, though: "Does this bus go *for* x?" would not be correct.)

Answer (score -1):

If I wanted to know how to get to X on a bus I would ask "How do I get to X from a bus?"

Problems with "Does this bus go to X?" include the fact that a correct answer ("yes" or "no") does not actually tell you how to get to X; you don't know which stop to get off or if you have to transfer. In addition, the bus may go to X but there could be another bus that is much faster or cheaper.

As others have pointed out, "Do you go to X?" does not tell you whether the bus goes to X or not.

Comment: I've never heard *from* used in place of *on* like that.  In fact I'd understand that as a different question: "How do I get to X *after getting off* the bus?" (having already established that the bus goes towards X).  Fair points that the other suggestions are closed questions, but "Which stop do I need to get off at?" is an obvious follow-up if the first answer is "yes"; and covering all the other complexities you've introduced is a different conversation entirely.